# accessing unordered_maps as pointers

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

For some reason, I am having trouble editing values in my unordered_map, and am wondering what I'm doing wrong.

In the following code, `parameter`is a struct.  For some reason, the following code is throwing a syntax error, not liking the [.

```
void MyClass::setParameter(string name, parameter param) {
    if (this->param_name_to_data == nullptr) {
        //create it lazily
        this->param_name_to_data = new unordered_map<string, parameter>();
    }
    this->param_name_to_data->[name] = param;
}
```

The dictionary id declared in the corresponding .h file as:

```
private:
 std::unordered_map<std::string, parameter> * param_name_to_data = nullptr;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some reason why you dynamically allocate the `unordered_map`?

Comment: I'll probably switch it to statically allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`param_name_to_data->[name] = param;` is not a valid syntax

when the compiler sees `->` it looks for either a member variable or a member function. the statement `->[...]` is meaningless since `[]` alone is neither a member variable nor a function.

you can write instead

```
(*param_name_to_data)[name] = param;
```

or turn the pointer to reference first

```
auto& map = *param_name_to_data;
map[name] = param;
```

you can also use the ugly literal form of

```
param_name_to_data->operator[] (name) = param
```

but the last one is discouraged.

Comment: I had thought I had seen ->[] somewhere in code before, which is why I was trying to use it.  Is there a reason why it's forbidden?

Comment: Thanks.  I still find it weird that it is unable to intelligently search for any other operator's abbreviation.  It's not a big deal, I'm just legitimately curious if there's some syntax-tree-ambiguity related reason or something that the compiler can't do that step.

Comment: it's basically like that because the standard didn't state that `->[]` is a valid syntax for calling `operator []` from a pointer. so no compiler implemented it. if the standard stated clearly that it should be valid, it would be correct

Comment: @user650261: "* I still find it weird that it is unable to intelligently search for any other operator's abbreviation.*" That's because it's not an "abbreviation". `operator[]` is the function's name. The `->` operator is grammatically intended to be followed by a member name of the type returned by `operator->`. `[]` is not a member name, so it fails.